# Correct use of select_related

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-orm, django-select-related

I currently have the following code that I want to optimize using select_related. The aim is to find out the set of BaseReward for which there is at least one Voucher with is_active = True

```
    class Basereward(models.Model):
        active = models.BooleanField()

    class Voucher(models.Model):
        reward = models.ForeignKey(BaseReward, related_name='reward_vouchers')
        is_active = models.BooleanField()
```

**View**

```
    qs = BaseReward.objects.filter(active=True).all()
    for reward in qs:
        if not reward.reward_vouchers.filter(is_active=True).all():
            qs = qs.exclude(id=reward.id)
    return qs
```

What is the correct way of doing it? I was thinking using the select_related using the reverse relationship, but the doc says it won't work
Any other way?

```
    qs = BaseReward.objects.filter(active=True).all().select_related(reward_vouchers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way around, get the unique set of `BaseReward` objects for where there is at least one `Voucher`:

```
Voucher.objects.filter(is_active=True).distinct(reward)
```

Comment: Thank you, in fact I need the final queryset returned (qs) to be a list of BaseReward objects. Current what you put would give me Voucher objects. Should I just add it at end: Voucher.objects.filter(is_active=True).distinct(reward).reward.all()?

Comment: All `Voucher` objects will have a `voucher.reward` object, which represents the `BaseReward` object for that voucher; not to mention what you wrote `distinct(reward).reward.all()` is not valid; if all you want is the reward object, try `distinct('reward').values('reward')`, see the documentation for [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#values) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Burhan. I tried distinct('reward').values('reward') and it gave me : [{'reward': 3}, {'reward': 4}, {'reward': 5}, {'reward': 6}, {'reward': 7}, {'reward': 8}, {'reward': 11}]

What I am looking for is a queryset that has BaseReward object, as I am writing this code in the get_queryset() method of a REST framework Viewset

Comment: Ah okay, so you need a `BaseReward` queryset - you'll need to build it yourself, try `BaseReward.objects.filter(pk__in=[i.reward.pk for i in Voucher.objects.filter(is_active=True).distinct(reward)])`. I think this is the best you can do, short of fetching all `BaseRewards` and then filtering each that has a `voucher_set.exists()`.